# Issues with Pihole in Macvlan Network: Host and Containers Unable to Communicate When Router DNS Points to Pihole

Tags: networking, docker, macvlan

I don't believe this is pihole related.

**TL/DR**
Pihole in docker with macvlan is unable to communicate with Host.
Other containers inside the macvlan IS able to communicate with Host.
It's not the standaard macvlan can't talk to Host issue.
Pihole is unreachable from host and vice versa ONLY when Router DNS server is assisgned to the Pihole container.

Used [this guide](https://blog.ivansmirnov.name/set-up-pihole-using-docker-macvlan-network/)
 to set up the macvlan.

The situation:

1x Pihole running on a Raspberry Pi (x.x.x.9) (Pi#1)

1x Pihole running on a Nuc (macvlan x.x.x.243) (Pi #2)

I'm trying to switch over to Pihole 2 and outphase the Pi.

So currently the router DNS is pointing to Pi 1. The Pihole 2 is up and running on the Nuc in Macvlan.
On the Nuc host, i can run `nslookup example.com 192.168.2.243`and it returns a value, so it WORKS.

So you would think it's safe to switch over and change the router to point to .243 right? wrong, after changing the router dns to point to .243 `nslookup example.com 192.168.2.243` doesnt work anymore! .243 suddenly becomes unreachable i don't understand.

```
user@nuc:~$ nslookup example.com 192.168.2.243
;; communications error to 192.168.2.243#53: connection refused
;; communications error to 192.168.2.243#53: connection refused
;; communications error to 192.168.2.243#53: connection refused
;; no servers could be reached
```

This return immediately no timeout or anything.

This is the macvlan:

```
sudo docker network create -d macvlan -o parent=eno1 \
--subnet 192.168.2.0/24 \
--gateway 192.168.2.100 \
--ip-range 192.168.2.240/28 \
--aux-address="nuc=192.168.2.254" \
macvlan
```

on boot i run this with a systemd servie:

```
ip link add macvlan-shim link eno1 type macvlan mode bridge
ip addr add 192.168.2.254/28 dev macvlan-shim
ip link set macvlan-shim up
ip route add 192.168.2.240/28 dev macvlan-shim
```

Pihole is able to download gravity list and update no problem on start.

From Nuc:

`sudo docker exec -ti pihole ping -c 4 google.com`

returns no packet loss, pihole can access the internet.

From the Nuc:

`ping 192.168.2.243`

```
user@nuc:~$ ping 192.168.2.243
PING 192.168.2.243 (192.168.2.243) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.2.21 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.21 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Not reachable - .21 is the host/nuc - this seems like a clue

From homeassistant container also running on the macvlan (.242)

`sudo docker exec -ti homeassistant ping -c 4 192.168.2.243`

```
PING 192.168.2.243 (192.168.2.243): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.2.243: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.058 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.243: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
```

So homeassistant in the same network of macvlan can access the pihole.

From the Nuc to homeassistant:

```
user@nuc:~$ ping 192.168.2.242
PING 192.168.2.242 (192.168.2.242) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.242: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.124 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.242: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.074 ms
```

Nuc to homeassistant is reachable - so this issue is not directly related to the macvlan

nmap when Router  DNS is not pointing to .243

```
user@nuc:~$ nmap 192.168.2.243
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-01-03 17:25 UTC
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.243
Host is up (0.00013s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
53/tcp open  domain
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

nmap when Router DNS IS pointing to the pihole at .243

```
user@nuc:~$ nmap 192.168.2.243
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-01-03 17:29 UTC
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.03 seconds


user@nuc:~$ nmap -Pn 192.168.2.243
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-01-03 17:29 UTC
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.243
Host is up (0.29s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on 192.168.2.243 are filtered

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 51.05 seconds
```

Sooo Tl/dr
It's not related to macvlan at least not directly. Host is able to communicate with other containers inside the macvlan.
Only pihole is giving issues when the router dns is pointing to it. And the issue is only for the host and the containers using the hosts network, including bridge networks as they can't resolve DNS. Can anyone give me an suggestion what i can try to debug this?

I also posted my whole setup [here](https://github.com/Marcel0024/home-server).